# Getting Verify Error for SqlCipher in android with iText lib

Tags: java, android, itext

While Installing app in mobile i am getting this error with the library iTextpdf

Without this iTextpdf library app runs fine
but After using this iTextpdf lib it give below error

```
  10605-10605/com.packagename.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.packagename.appname, PID: 10605
    java.lang.VerifyError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase at com.packagename.appname.MainApplication.createDaoSession(MainApplication.java:63)
  at com.packagename.appname.MainApplication.getDaoSession(MainApplication.java:54)
  at com.packagename.appname.managers.StateCityDetailsManager.getStateCityDetailsDao(StateCityDetailsManager.java:40)
  at com.packagename.appname.managers.StateCityDetailsManager.loadAll(StateCityDetailsManager.java:26)
  at com.packagename.appname.activities.SplashActivity.apiCalls(SplashActivity.java:164)
  at com.packagename.appname.activities.SplashActivity.callApi(SplashActivity.java:133)
  at com.packagename.appname.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:78)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is My Gradle :

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':wibmoSDK')
    compile files('libs/PayU-release.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.3.1-2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.6'
```

Please Let me know if any solution found....

Comment: Did you find solution. If you have let me know. thank you advance

Comment: This issue was due to progaurd as there is few files which i need to neglect which is causing error for devices which is 4.4 or below